# Corrupt root site collection - Any risks to delete?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

**Overview:**

We have SharePoint 2016, on-premise. Within it, we have a web application that contains three HostName Site Collections, mapped to three different subdomains. I'm noticing that the root site collection (i.e. the one where the hostname matches the web application) is corrupt/missing. Meaning, the only place it is visible is in CA. Meaning, we can't

- Navigate to it via http. When we do, we get a 404 NOT FOUND
- All attempts to retreive it via PowerShell (i.e. get-spsite {url}) fail saying that SharePoint cannot find an SPWeb at {Url}.

There is no content on this root site collection. It has no significance other than it being broken it is preventing SharePoint Search from crawling the other HostNamed Site Collections defined under the same web application.

**Proposal:**

It's obvious that there is something seriously wrong with the root site collection. Since it has no content, in Central Administration we are going to delete the root site collection, and recreate it. We're hoping that by doing so, this will restore Search.

**Question(s):**

1. Has anyone else attempted or been in this situation before?
2. Were there any implications/risks to the other host-named site collections under the same web application?
3. Any lessons learnt that you can share before we action the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any risks to delete the root site collection. It's the same as deleting other site collections. It has nothing to do with your ther host-named site collections.

And I used to delete it successfully. Just in case, it's a good choice to back up the DB first before the deletion.